# tex4ebook with diacritics and tibetan font

Tags: fonts, tex4ht, font-encodings, tex4ebook

I'm trying to convert to ePub an english commentary of a Tibetan text which includes some mantras in Tibetan writing and helpful pronunciation, using tex4ebook. The follow test.tex is an example:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}   
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ctib}

\begin{document}

Some text ...

O\d{M} \=A\d{H}  H\=U\d{M}

{\tib \om, ma nxi pa\V{de}{ma} \hung \hrih:}

\end{document}
```

Compilation with the following works as expected:

```
lualatex test.tex or pdflatex test.tex
```

To create the epub version I am trying:

```
 tex4ebook -l -c config test.tex
```

end config.cfg is:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\CutAt{section}
\makeatletter
% Various helper functions
% default font size
\newcommand\emwidth{16}
\let\emwidth\f@size
% convert pt to rem
\newcommand\CalcRem[1]{\strip@pt\dimexpr(#1)/\emwidth}
  \Configure{graphics*}  
         {svg}  
          {\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg
          \space style="width:\CalcRem{\Gin@req@width}em;"
          }%  
          \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg}
         }  
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.svg,.png,.jpg}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\AddFontFace[4]{%
\Css{@font-face {
    font-family: #1;
    src: local("#2"),
        url('#3');
    #4
 }}
\special{t4ht+@File: #3}
}
\edef\CurrentFontFamily{rmfamily}
\newcommand\SetFontFamily[1]{
\edef\CurrentFontFamily{#1}
}
\newcommand\NormalFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}}

\newcommand\BoldFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: bold;font-style: normal;}}
\newcommand\ItalicFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: normal;font-style: italic;}}
\newcommand\BoldItalicFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: bold;font-style: italic;}}
```

The problem is the output about mantras and the diacritics characters in the ePub version.
Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: would you mind if the mantras came as a picture?

Comment: I wouldn't prefer but as a first solution it is ok. A mantra is a sequence of sillabe and a single picture of them is ok. How can I generate a picture from the mantras? A different case is the characters \d{M} or \d{H}. The output is a picture but the effect of glue characters and picture is ugly. There is a way to print that characters? Thanks

Comment: I am able to generate a picture for the mantras and insert it into the text. Sorry. What about the diacritics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems: letters with dot under accents are converted as pictures and Tibetan text comes as mix of Unicode letters and pictures with some letters missing:

[image]

We have to provide configuration with Unicode values for each letter with dot bellow accent. I took a look at how accenting commands are configured in `tex4ht` and found the following configuration:

```
\expand:after{\expand:after{\Configure{accent}}%
 \csname OT1\string\d\endcsname}%
 \csname OT1\string\d\endcsname{{}{}}
 {\a:accents{d}{#1}}     {\b:accents{d}{#1}{#2}}
```

It looks a little bit cryptic, but the point is that there should be list of letters followed by Unicode codepoints for the combined letter in this place: `\csname OT1\string\d\endcsname{{}{}}`. When configuration for a letter is missing, it is converted as image, as can be seen in your sample.

It should look like this instead:

```
\expand:after{\expand:after{\Configure{accent}}%
 \csname OT1\string\d\endcsname}%
  \csname OT1\string\d\endcsname{A{1EA0}a{1Ea1}B{1E04}b{1E05}D{1E0C}d{1E0D}%
  E{1EB8}e{1EB9}H{1E24}h{1E25}I{1ECA}i{1ECB}%
  K{1E32}k{1E33}L{1E36}l{1E37}M{1E42}m{1E43}%
  N{1E46}n{1E47}O{1ECC}o{1ECD}R{1E5A}r{1E5B}%
  S{1E62}s{1E63}T{1E6C}t{1E6D}U{1EE4}u{1EE5}%
  V{1E7E}v{1E7F}W{1E88}w{1E89}Y{1EF4}y{1EF5}%
  {}{}}
     {\a:accents{d}{#1}}     {\b:accents{d}{#1}{#2}}
```

Regarding the mantras, `ctib` uses some Metafont trickery to convert the transliterated text to images. It seems that it is not realistic to expect it to translate to Unicode flawlessly, so I would convert it to an image instead. You can introduce some simple command, which will be used in the document:

```
\newcommand\mantra[1]{\bgroup\tib #1\egroup}
...
\mantra{\om, ma nxi pa\V{de}{ma} \hung \hrih:}
```

And redefine it in the config file:

```
\renewcommand\mantra[1]{\Picture+{}\bgroup\tib #1\egroup\EndPicture}
```

The full configuration file would look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\CutAt{section}
\makeatletter
% Various helper functions
% default font size
\newcommand\emwidth{16}
\let\emwidth\f@size
% convert pt to rem
\newcommand\CalcRem[1]{\strip@pt\dimexpr(#1)/\emwidth}
  \Configure{graphics*}  
         {svg}  
          {\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg
          \space style="width:\CalcRem{\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname}em;"
          }%  
          \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg}
         }  
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.svg,.png,.jpg}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\AddFontFace[4]{%
\Css{@font-face {
    font-family: #1;
    src: local("#2"),
        url('#3');
    #4
 }}
\special{t4ht+@File: #3}
}
\edef\CurrentFontFamily{rmfamily}
\newcommand\SetFontFamily[1]{
\edef\CurrentFontFamily{#1}
}
\newcommand\NormalFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}}

\newcommand\BoldFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: bold;font-style: normal;}}
\newcommand\ItalicFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: normal;font-style: italic;}}
\newcommand\BoldItalicFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: bold;font-style: italic;}}

%  patch for \mantra command
\renewcommand\mantra[1]{\Picture+{}\bgroup\tib #1\egroup\EndPicture}
% Use the following configuration if you want to convert mantras to SVG instead of PNG
% Note that the compilation time is longer and the resulting SVG file much bigger
% \Configure{Picture}{.svg}
% Configuration for \d accent
\catcode`\:=11
\expand:after{\expand:after{\Configure{accent}}%
 \csname OT1\string\d\endcsname}%
  \csname OT1\string\d\endcsname{A{1EA0}a{1Ea1}B{1E04}b{1E05}D{1E0C}d{1E0D}%
  E{1EB8}e{1EB9}H{1E24}h{1E25}I{1ECA}i{1ECB}%
  K{1E32}k{1E33}L{1E36}l{1E37}M{1E42}m{1E43}%
  N{1E46}n{1E47}O{1ECC}o{1ECD}R{1E5A}r{1E5B}%
  S{1E62}s{1E63}T{1E6C}t{1E6D}U{1EE4}u{1EE5}%
  V{1E7E}v{1E7F}W{1E88}w{1E89}Y{1EF4}y{1EF5}%
  {}{}}
     {\a:accents{d}{#1}}     {\b:accents{d}{#1}{#2}}
\catcode`\:=12

\EndPreamble
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is a perfect solution. It works perfectly. Thanks.